# Always watch videos in HD on YouTube

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to always watch YouTube videos in HD (when available) and without changing the resolution yourself?

YouTube offers 360 standard for small player, 480 for large and 720 for full screen.

I would like to have the 720 video high definition version. Always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a setting in YouTube to do this.  You can achieve this by installing [this GreaseMonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/39167) though.

> **YouTube HD Suite**
>
> **Script Summary:** Perfect package to enjoy HD videos in YouTube. Always watching or downloading the highest quality format ( HD 1440p /
>   HD 1080p / HD 720p / HQ FLV / MP4 iPod ). Add download icons in video
>   list page.
>
> **Version:** 3.4.1

Comment: Works like a charm!